# Eclipse DDMS and Jelly Bean . I don't see the Sdcard

Tags: android, usb, android-4.2-jelly-bean, ddms

I like to transfer Files from my Eclipse ( Java ) to the tablet over DDMS. This worked fine since I got an update to Jelly Bean.
I guess it is because connecting to UBS automatically activates Media Device. I already tried to switch between MTS & PTP but both doesn't work.

Debugging and starting the app over DDMS works fine and the Android Tablet is recognized in DDMS. The problem is, that the sdcard has only a file-icon and is not accessable.

Any hints ?
[image]
Regards